# How can i setup end to end code debugging for JBPM application

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, drools, jbpm

Project uses bpmn files for handling main part of the flows.Currently i have set up code debugging for java part which this way is useless for bpmn files because hundreds of lines embedded to script tasks iniside bpmns.If i set up debug for bpmns it would be useless for java part.Question is to find some way to setup debugging for both.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the jBPM version but [jBPM Eclipse Plugin 6.0](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html) comes with debugging capabilities as explained in [18.2 Debugging](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html#d0e12658), however:

> Note that we currently don't allow you to put breakpoints on the nodes within a process directly. You can however put breakpoints inside any Java code you might have (i.e. your application code that is invoking the engine or invoked by the engine, listeners, etc.) or inside rules (that could be evaluated in the context of a process). At these breakpoints, you can then inspect the internal state of all your process instances.

If installing Eclipse plugin is not possible you would have to debug through the Java code of jBPM engine. It's doable, but not pleasant experience.